# ignore JSON property and get only values

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I pull some data from an API which returns something like this

```
[{"id":21},{"id":22},{"id":24}]
```

I will have to post the data received to a database via a different API, but when I'm sending I want it to be sent like `[21,22,24]`
For example the variable that receives the data from the API is called `valuesToSend` which comes `[{"id":21},{"id":22},{"id":24}]` but when posting, it should be `[21,22,24]`

```
postToDb(){
alert(this.valuesToSend)
}
```

Comment: Read about [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array)

Comment: `this.valuesToSend.map(a => a.id)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the object key, using ES6, Array.map() and object destructuring, you could do it like this

```
const a = [{ "id": 21 }, { "id": 22 }, { "id": 24 }];
const valuesToSend = a.map(({ id }) => id);
alert(valuesToSend)
```